# Почему не получается запустить hot module replacement (React,Webpack)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Не получается запустить hmr. Перехожу по ссылке
 http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server/bundle

И получаю ошибку...

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...


invariant.js:44Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
at invariant (invariant.js:44)
at Object._renderNewRootComponent (ReactMount.js:311)
at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (ReactMount.js:401)
at render (ReactMount.js:422)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:36)
at mightThrow (jquery.js:3570)
at process (jquery.js:3638)
invariant @ invariant.js:44
_renderNewRootComponent @ ReactMount.js:311
 _renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js:401
 render @ ReactMount.js:422
(anonymous) @ index.js:36
mightThrow @ jquery.js:3570
process @ jquery.js:3638


client:41 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

index.html

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

webpack.config.js

```
  ar webpack = require('webpack');

 module.exports = {
 devtool:'source-map',
 entry: [
     './app/index.js'
 ],
  output: {
     path: __dirname + "./dist",
     filename: "bundle.js",
     publicPath:'/'
 },
 module: {
     loaders:[
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude:'/node_modules/',
            loader:'babel-loader',
             query: {
                 presets: ["es2015", "react", "react-hmre"]
             }
        },
    }
    plugins: [
     new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
     new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
 ],
 devServer: {
     //hot:true,
     //inline:true,
   port: 3000
 },


}
```

Пробовал оборачивать render() в $(document).ready - нету результат.

Comment: В http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server/bundle при просмотре кода есть <div id="root"></div> ???

Comment: нет, только iframe и header

Comment: http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server/ - переход по этой ссылке должен показывать список файлов в папке, где запущен сервер. У меня же тут грузится iframe, и кое-как , если не добавлять --hot --inline, делает обновление, правда только по ctrl+s, и то с интервалом не меньше секунд 20 и с перебоями...

Answer (score 0):

ну у тебя ошибка

> Target container is not a DOM element

нету контейнера куда рендерить

А так же в entry должно быть

```
[
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './app/index.js'
]
```